# Theming Bootstrap(4) Using CSS Vars in SCSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm trying to implement Bootstrap on a site where the user can dynamically change the colour scheme.
I've done this using CSS vars, following [this guide](https://blog.wick.technology/runtime-dynamic-bootstrap-theme/).
It generally works, but when anything uses the lighten or darken functions (alerts for example) it doesn't work.

The CSS vars are declared in the head of the HTML like so;

```
<style type="text/css">
:root {
    --primary: #3490dc;
    --primary-h: 207;
    --primary-s: 71%;
    --primary-l: 53%;
    --primary-a: 1;
    --secondary: #6c757d;
    --secondary-h: 207;
    --secondary-s: 71%;
    --secondary-l: 53%;
    --secondary-a: 1;
    --success: hsl(207, 71%, 53%);
    --success-h: 207;
    --success-s: 71%;
    --success-l: 53%;
    --success-a: 1;
    --info: #17a2b8;
    --info-h: 188;
    --info-s: 78%;
    --info-l: 41%;
    --info-a: 1;
    --warning: #ffc107;
    --warning-h: 188;
    --warning-s: 78%;
    --warning-l: 41%;
    --warning-a: 1;
    --danger: #dc3545;
    --danger-h: 188;
    --danger-s: 78%;
    --danger-l: 41%;
    --danger-a: 1;
    --light: #f8f9fa;
    --light-h: 188;
    --light-s: 78%;
    --light-l: 41%;
    --light-a: 1;
    --dark: #343a40;
    --dark-h: 188;
    --dark-s: 78%;
    --dark-l: 41%;
    --dark-a: 1;
    --font-family-sans-serif: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Roboto, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Arial, sans-serif, &quot;Apple Color Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Symbol&quot;;
    --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, &quot;Liberation Mono&quot;, &quot;Courier New&quot;, monospace;
}
</style>
```

When I inspect the alert element the console is showing;

```
.alert-success {
    color: hsla(calc((
0deg + var(--success-h)) / 2), calc((0% + var(--success-s)) / 2), calc((0% + var(--success-l)) / 2), calc((1 + var(--success-a, 1)) / 2));
    background-color: hsla(calc((
0deg + var(--success-h)) / 2), calc((0% + var(--success-s)) / 2), calc((100% + var(--success-l)) / 2), calc((1 + var(--success-a, 1)) / 2));
    border-color: hsla(calc((
0deg + var(--success-h)) / 2), calc((0% + var(--success-s)) / 2), calc((100% + var(--success-l)) / 2), calc((1 + var(--success-a, 1)) / 2));
}
```

But the computed it showing;

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Hence no colour on the alert background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you do actually want to keep the `deg`. Rather than removing that from Bootstrap, you just need to update your variable to include the same `deg` units as well.

As your code stands now, you are adding `0deg + 207`, but you should be adding `0deg + 207deg`. Adding these units will cause your styles to start working properly.

As a rule of thumb, all of your styles should include their appropriate units, matching what Bootstrap already has in place:

```css
:root {
  --success-h: 207deg;
  --success-s: 71%;
  --success-l: 53%;
  --success-a: 1;
}
```

The only other call-out I'd make is that for your opacity value, you are currently adding `1 + 1` which results in an opacity of `2`, which exceeds the cap of `1` by 100%.

If you are adding `1` + your variable value simply as a fall-back in case the value doesn't exist, you may want to consider using default values. Your code in its current state would require a **negative** opacity value (e.g. `-.5`) to make a color translucent. If you would prefer to use `1` as a fallback value for when the variable doesn't exist, you can do so by putting the default value after a comma in your variable reference like this:

```css
.alert-success {
  color: hsla(calc(var(--success-h, 0deg) / 2), calc(var(--success-s, 0%) / 2), calc(var(--success-l, 0%) / 2), calc(var(--success-a, 1) / 2));
  background-color: hsla(calc(var(--success-h, 0deg) / 2), calc(var(--success-s, 0%) / 2), calc(var(--success-l, 100%) / 2), calc(var(--success-a, 1) / 2));
  border-color: hsla(calc(var(--success-h, 0deg) / 2), calc(var(--success-s, 0%) / 2), calc(var(--success-l, 100%) / 2), calc(var(--success-a, 1) / 2));
}
```

If all your additions were intentional, simply disregard this last bit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the 0deg stuff.

However. i managed to get it to work if i replace 0deg with just 0.

```css
.alert-success {
    color: hsla(calc((
0 + var(--success-h)) / 2), calc((0% + var(--success-s)) / 2), calc((0% + var(--success-l)) / 2), calc((1 + var(--success-a, 1)) / 2));
    background-color: hsla(calc((
0 + var(--success-h)) / 2), calc((0% + var(--success-s)) / 2), calc((100% + var(--success-l)) / 2), calc((1 + var(--success-a, 1)) / 2));
    border-color: hsla(calc((
0 + var(--success-h)) / 2), calc((0% + var(--success-s)) / 2), calc((100% + var(--success-l)) / 2), calc((1 + var(--success-a, 1)) / 2));
}
```

Comment: Where in the bootstrap scss do I need to update to remove the 0deg?

Comment: I'm not really sure. But what you can do, is to define this .alert-success class again, to override the old one. I think that would work.

Comment: Yes it would, but I was after a solution that would work in scss otherwise I'll end up having to redefine half the classes.